# How to create a MySQL Database with a value of +1 if a DB with a matching name exists?

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh, cpanel

I'm working on a bash script and need a bit of help, this is what I currently have.

```
mysql -e "create database if not exists ${UN}_${SQLBASE}"
mysql -Be "GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, CREATE ROUTINE ON \`"$UN"\\_"$SQLBASE"\`.* TO '"$UN"_"$SQLUSER"'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$SQLPASS';FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
```

Pretty much, I need to know how I can create a database with the name cpanel_db1, if that exists then automatically move up to the number up. ex cpanel_db2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be done something like this:

```
username="usernamedb"
password="passworddb"

database="cpanel_db"
databases=$(mysql -u $username -p$password -Bse 'show databases'|grep $database)

max=1

if [ -z "$databases" ];then
    mysql -u $username -p$password -Bse "create database ${database}$max"
else
    for cdatabase in $databases
    do
        cdatabasenumber=$(echo $cdatabase|awk -F"db" '{print $2}')
        if [ $cdatabasenumber -gt $max ]; then
            max=$cdatabasenumber
        fi
    done
    let max++

    mysql -u $username -p$password -Bse "create database ${database}$max"
fi
```

~
~